# How to Determine the Size of MSADO Command Parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parameters, ado

I am new to MS ADO and trying to understand how to set the size on command parameters as created by the

```
command.CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28VS.85%29.aspx) says the following:

> Size 
> Optional. A Long value that
>   specifies the maximum length for the
>   parameter value in characters or
>   bytes.

...

> If you specify a variable-length data
>   type in the Type argument, you must
>   either pass a Size argument or set the
>   Size property of the Parameter object
>   before appending it to the Parameters
>   collection; otherwise, an error
>   occurs.

1.) What should one pass for fixed-size parameters? Is it a "don't care"?

I was a bit confused by the example found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675080%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), in which they set size to 3 for an adInteger parameter with Value set to a variant of type VT_I2

```
pPrmByRoyalty->Type = adInteger;
pPrmByRoyalty->Size = 3;
pPrmByRoyalty->Direction = adParamInput;
pPrmByRoyalty->Value = vtroyal;
```

VT_I2 implies two bytes. A tagVARIANT struct is 16 bytes. How did they land on three? I see that the enum value for adInteger happens to be three, but I suspect that is just a coincidence.

So it's a bit confusing what to pass for fixed-size parameters. The team I'm working with has always passed sizeof(int) for adInteger, and it seems to work. Is that correct?

Now, for "variable-length" parameters: we are instructed by the documentation to pass "the maximum length .. in characters or bytes".

2.) For adVarChar, is it sufficient to pass the max width as defined in the database?

3.) What about the Wide types (e.g. adVarWChar)? Is it characters or bytes?

4.) How about adVariant, which could contain fixed- or variable-length data?

5.) Do arrays ever come into play here? (we don't pass them as parameters, just curious)

Any references or personal insights are welcome.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used this interface, but I believe I used sizeof(type) for fixed-size args.  I suspect the lib actually throws away the size anyway, so you could probably put any value there.

I would pass the number of chars for strings, regardless of wide/narrow.  It's safer, and if you're wrong you'll find out by data truncation rather than inexplicable insert failures buried under a deep stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) size is optional for fixed length parameters, so you can pass vtMissing (comutil.h). BTW, my size (connecting to SQL Server) for adInteger is 4 and type is VT_I4, VT_I2 is size 2 and adSmallInt.

2) That should work, I guess. Remind to take the max width of the parameter as defined in the database, not any table column you compare it with. The size might be used for allocation, so you must assure that the size is big enough so that any value that might be filled in fits in.

3) Probably characters.

Regarding 4 and 5 I don't know in which scenario one would want to pass an adVariant or array to the database engine.